# Is there an emulator for Google Assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am developing Google Actions for Google Assistant. Is there an emulator of Google Assistant for Linux available? I believe this would be easier during development, instead of having to use my phone all the time.

I know there is https://console.actions.google.com, but I am not sure if this has all capabilities built in. Should Google Actions (such as cards, suggestion clips, carousel, ...) also work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do almost all of your development using the actions simulator: https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/simulator

There are a few exceptions dealing with cross device scenarios and intent invocation for Android.

The simulator is better than developing on a phone since it provides detailed logging and request/response JSON payloads.

Comment: Thank you. Currently, my cards are not showing so I assumed that this functionality is not available in the console. I will focus on get that working first, as I understand that it should work.

Comment: Cards are supported in the console. There are some restrictions on cards such as the number of chars, so double check that.

Comment: That's good to know and very useful! Though, I am still having troubles to figure out why it is not working on my end. I asked my question regarding the cards here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125469/why-is-the-carousel-not-showing-in-the-console-simulator